# How to set background image in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am very new to `WP` apps and don't know how to set the `back-ground` image in `app.xaml` file for whole application in `Windows Phone 8` app. Up-till now, i have placed some `controls` over it but fail to set background image. I have seen some material but did not work. Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add a Common Grid Style which uses Image as background.And place it under App.xaml.Resources.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LayoutGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
          <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/bgImage.jpg"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And use it for the Root grid of your page.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Style="{StaticResource LayoutGridStyle}">
//Content goes here
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following in the InitializePhoneApplication method of my app.xaml.cs. The effect is that every page has the same background image, and there's no flashing/blanking upon page navigation

```
 RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame
 {
    Background = new ImageBrush()
    {
       ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/Russel_Logo_ep2s.png", UriKind.Relative)),
       Opacity = 0.3,
       Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None,
       AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center,
       AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center
    }
 };
```