# How to set background image globally windows phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, background, windows-phone-8.1

I'm brand new to windows phone and it seems like windows phone 8.1 has lots of changes compare with windows phone 8. How can I change the background image for my app globally, without declare it again and again in every single views.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the ImageBrush in your App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="BgImage" ImageSource="Assets/Logo.png" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Set the Background of your rootFrame in App.xaml.cs -> OnLaunched method:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    #if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
    #endif

    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        // TODO: diesen Wert auf eine Cachegröße ändern, die für Ihre Anwendung geeignet ist
        rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

        if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            // TODO: Zustand von zuvor angehaltener Anwendung laden
        }

        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
        {
            this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
            foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
            {
                this.transitions.Add(c);
            }
        }

        rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
        rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }
    }

    rootFrame.Background = (ImageBrush)Resources["BgImage"];
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

And than make your page background transparent.

Here is my Page.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello World !"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm following the first answer in this topic but somehow the background doesn't show up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013441/how-to-set-background-image-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: Make sure that you havent set a background in your page, which is the default: 
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"

Comment: That's y i tried to delete the line Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" but it gave me error as invalid markup

Comment: Edited the answer and added my Page.xaml

Comment: Please check my edited question. I remove Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" already. The background still doesn't show up. :(((((

Comment: Because you set a background for your grid in your 'LayoutGridStyle'

Comment: I dont get what you mean. How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the Style property of your <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

Comment: Your App.xaml.cs is running fine ? No exceptions ?
You set the background of the root frame in your App.xaml.cs ?
Try setting the background of your grid to transparent: 
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

Comment: It runs just fine, no exceptions at all. I set the background in App.xaml. Already set Background="Transparent" . still doesnt work :(

Comment: please add your app.xaml.cs

Comment: Please check App.xaml.cs I have just added

Comment: I can't see where you set the background of the rootFrame
Add: rootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0));
above this lines:
// Ensure the current window is active
Window.Current.Activate();

Comment: I didnt add rootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0)); All I add is in the App.xaml above because I want to add a picture as background, not background color.

Comment: <ImageBrush x:Key="BgImage" ImageSource="Assets/Logo.png" /> showing error "Key attribute can be used only on a tag contained in a IDictionary type property"

Comment: Updated answer with my full App.xaml

Comment: rootFrame.Background = (ImageBrush)Resources["BgImage"]; has null exception. Here is how I declare it  Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            rootFrame.Background = (ImageBrush)Resources["BgImage"];
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();

Comment: Updated my answer again with the OnLaunched method in App.xaml.cs